# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1. in a sample project from github

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to compile this project: https://github.com/dakatso/SpeexExample

The project as is gives errors during gradle sync (it says something called `mipsel-linux-android` was not found). I have made changes to the following files:

gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
#Tue Jul 07 16:26:18 KST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-all.zip
```

Project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2'        // ORIGINAL
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar
Required by:
    project :
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

If I create a new project from scratch I use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0' but for this project nothing seems to work. How can I get this project to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `google()` repo.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() //<--
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() //<--
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Also check the **gradle** version.
The plugin 3.2.1 [requires at least](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) the version 4.6:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Is this project using some old style gradle.build files that cannot be used in latest Android studio?

Comment: Try to update gradle plugin to 4.0.0 and gradle to 6.1.1.

Comment: I've done this but I get errors in the other app level build.gradle files. I'm wondering is this project itself does not compile in Android Studio 4.0.