# "compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle " even though compileSdkVersion is added

Tags: android, gradle

This is a follow up to my question here: [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1. in a sample project from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770507/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-2-1-in-a-sample-project-from-gi)

I am trying to compile the project given here: https://github.com/dakatso/SpeexExample

To get rid of gradle sync errors, I had to first change the project level gradle.build and gradle-wrapper.properties file. The changes made are as shown in the linked question and it's answer ([Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1. in a sample project from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770507/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-2-1-in-a-sample-project-from-gi))

I'm however getting errors in the app level gradle.build files in both the /library and /sample folders. I have tried to make some modifications but I get an error that says `compileSdkVersion is not specified` although it's specified in the file. I think this project was created using an older version of android studio and gradle, which do not apply to the latest android studio  (4.0). Here are the app level build.gradle files (shows original code as well as my modifications):

build.gradle for /library:

```
// apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'        // ORIGINAL
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

model {
    android {
        // compileSdkVersion = 24       // ORIGINAL
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion = '24.0.0'

        defaultConfig {
            // ORIGINAL
            // minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
            // targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24

            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 26

        }

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir 'src/main/jni/include'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = 'speex'
            platformVersion = '9'
            toolchain = 'clang'

            CFlags.add('-DFIXED_POINT')
            CFlags.add('-DUSE_KISS_FFT')
            CFlags.add('-DEXPORT=\"\"')
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle for /sample:

```
// apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'        // ORIGINAL
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

model {
    android {
        // compileSdkVersion = 24       // ORIGINAL
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion = '24.0.0'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'com.speex.speexsample'
            // ORIGINAL
            // minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
            // targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 26

            versionCode = 1
            versionName = '1.0.0'
        }

        productFlavors {
            create("arm") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            }
            create("arm7") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
            create("arm8") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            }
            create("x86") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
            }
            create("x86-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
            }
            create("mips") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
            }
            create("mips-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
            }
            create("all")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ORIGINAL
    // compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    // compile project(':library')

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'        // ORIGINAL
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'              // ORIGINAL
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    implementation project(':library')

}
```

What should be modified in these files to get this project to compile?

Comment: It is based on the `gradle-experimental`. Remove the `model` block. Just use:  `android { ... }`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Removing `model` gives this error on gradle sync: Could not find method sources() for arguments [build_ckwpzmz3kdwwxj3uf21uqur86$_run_closure1$_closure3@2c887c80] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti this error is in the build.gradle file for /library

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the gradle files are from an old [experimental gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental), and you've now changed it to the current library/application plugins.

You can likely get rid of the compileSdkVersion warning by removing the `model { }` block and thus make the `android { }` a top-level block. Expect to see more migration issues going forward.

Comment: Removing `model` gives this error on gradle sync: Could not find method sources() for arguments [build_ckwpzmz3kdwwxj3uf21uqur86$_run_closure1$_closure3@2c887c80] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Comment: this error is in the build.gradle file for /library

Comment: Yes the syntax with different plugins are different. Migration from one DSL to another requires further work.

Comment: Is this a difficult task? If this is not trivial, is there a way to get the original github code to compile on Android Studio 4.0, or is it too old to be supported?

Answer (score 0):

In my case using plain old cordova I had simply not bootstrapped the project from the command line for the first time. Doing the following:

`cordova build android`

in the command line fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the app/build.gradle file and locate the line that reads:

**compileSdk compileSdkVersion**

Replace the above line with the following:

**compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion**

This change will ensure that the compileSdkVersion is correctly referenced from the project's root ext properties.